# Will HTML5 offline mode be supported in Internet Explorer 9?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, offline-mode

I understand HTML5 off-line mode is not supported in Internet Explorer 8. Do we know if it will be in IE9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not known yet, according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/)

Comment: Correct; no such support has been announced.

Answer (score 0):

New development! IE 10 supports Application Cache ! [Linky-dink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)